# From a set of numbers, odds of a number being/not being selected when drawn randomly $x$ times

Tags: probability, statistics

Apologies if the title is unclear, This is my first question here.

Anyway,

Say I have a set of numbered balls i.e $(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)$. I want to make a $15$ digit number by randomly drawing one ball from the set, recording it's value then putting the ball back. Rinse and repeat fifteen times.

How would I calculate The chances/odds of one of the balls (numbers) not being present, being present once, twice etc.. in my $15$ digit number?

Many Thanks

Comment: What you're looking for is the _binomial_ probability distribution.

Comment: Thanks! Hadn't a clue what to search for to even try teach myself. I'll have a look around but still wouldn't be opposed to a a walk through of "binomial probability distribution" being used to solve the above ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

- The chance that a number $i$  will be  selected in one draw is
  $p=\frac1{10}$.
- The chance that a number $i$ will be selected $k$ times in $n$ draws is 
  $P(X=k)={n \choose k} \cdot  \left(p\right)^k\cdot (1-p)^{n-k}$
- $X$ is [binomial distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: Hmm, leave it with me, I'm sure i'll get it thanks to you and @Arthur's help

Comment: @DublinMeUp If not, feel free to ask.